# nginx $is_args$args equivalent in IIS Redirect Module?

Tags: nginx, iis, url-rewriting, query-string

I am trying to find the equivalent in IIS/Redirect module for the following nginx config:

```
sub_filter .ts .ts$is_args$args;
sub_filter .m3u8 .m3u8$is_args$args;
sub_filter_once off;
sub_filter_types application/vnd.apple.mpegurl;
```

The goal is to append the query string parameter, that is passed to the firts request of an HLS playlist (.m3u8) to all subsequent requests, variant-playlistes (.m3u8) and TS-chunks (.ts files). This is used for passing the token-parameter from the master playlist to all further requests.

How can this be accomplished with IIS?

Thanks!

Comment: I am not familiar with nginx, and I don’t know what $is_args$args means, but you can tell me directly what your needs in iis are, maybe I can help you achieve.

Comment: We need to append the query string of a first request of a client to each subsequent requests from this client. In detail: the client requests a master playlist (.m3u8) with a token as URL query string, which is generated from our application. Since all further requests are made from within video.js or JW Player, we cannot add this token from our application. So the server needs to append this query string automatically to every request. This is done by nginx with the configration I posed. Now I need ti implement this on IIS. Thanks for your help.